# Can't get supported resolutions of the camera for image capturing using QCamera in Qt 5.0.2 (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, camera

I am trying to write a simple program for taking photos from the webcam using Qt.
There is an example project in the Qt Creator, where QCamera is used to take photos and record video. But it is not working the right way. I can't get supported resolutions of the camera using method QCameraImageCapture::supportedResolutions(). A null QList object is returned, and camera is always capturing images with 640x480 resolutions.
OS is Ubuntu 11.04. Same problem occurs on Windows XP.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I have answered nearly the same question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21140214/2452081

In short:
Portable solution can be gstreamer, but if Windows DirectShow solution is enough for you [download my code from here](http://www.craftunique.com/qt-dscamera.cpp)